# Can nNumberOfBytesToWrite ever be different from lpNumberOfBytesWritten or 0 when using WriteFile function on a Named pipe?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

According to the documentation the answer is Yes. If the named pipe is used with `PIPE_NOWAIT` and `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`, `WriteFile` should write the bytes to the buffer until it fills up or all the requested bytes are written.

> A WriteFile operation is affected by the wait mode of a pipe handle
>   when there is insufficient space in the pipe's buffer. With a
>   blocking-wait handle, the write operation cannot succeed until
>   sufficient space is created in the buffer by a thread reading from the
>   other end of the pipe. With a nonblocking-wait handle, the write
>   operation returns a nonzero value immediately, without writing any
>   bytes (for a message-type pipe) or after writing as many bytes as the
>   buffer holds (for a byte-type pipe).

But, my experiments contradict this statement. When I use `WriteFile` in `PIPE_NOWAIT` mode, regardless of the type mode (`PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` or `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`), the `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` is always equal to `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` when the pipe buffer space is larger than `nNumberOfBytesToWrite`, and equal to `0` when the pipe buffer space is smaller than `nNumberOfBytesToWrite`.

I'm only expecting this behavior with `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`, not with `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`.

Am I misreading the documentation?

Comment: I don't think so, but the documentation may well be incorrect on this point.  Note that `PIPE_NOWAIT` is supported only for compatibility purposes, i.e., to allow programs written decades ago to continue to function.  For new code, you should be using asynchronous I/O instead.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you! I was not aware that PIPE_NOWAIT is old stuff.